# Which of the following staement/s is/are true about $A$ if $A$ is row equivalent to $R\ $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, independence, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ be an arbitrary $5 \times 5$ real matrix row equivalent to the following matrix $:$ $$R = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -3 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Then which of the following statement/s is/are true?
>
> $(a)$ The first two columns of $A$ are linearly independent.
>
> $(b)$ The last four columns of $A$ generate a space of dimension $3.$

I think when we reduce the rows of $A$ by elementary row operations to form $R$ then the independence of the columns remains unaltered and $(a)$ and $(b)$ are true for $A$ iff similar statements are true for $R.$ Am I right with my reasoning?

Comment: $R$ is row-equivalent to itself. So, to be true, a statement should at least apply to $R$.

Comment: @Taladris for $R$ the statements are clearly true. But what if I take any arbitrary $5 \times 5$ matrix $A$ which is row equivalent to $R\ $?

Comment: I misread the statement (b) as "... space of dimension 4"